# How to draw only one, the newest point selected by pick_event?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to pick (add) marker to the curve. The marker may change the position many times, however eventually I need to plot only the newest (updated) marker and remove the old. 
Any ideas?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)for i in range(10):
pt, = ax1.plot(t, s, picker=5)


def onpick(event):

    if event.artist != pt:
        return True
    if not len(event.ind):
        return True
    ind = event.ind[0]
    ax1.plot(t[ind], s[ind], '|r', markersize='20')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return True


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling a new `plot()` and creating a new artist at every click, simply create an empty artist at initialization stage, and update its coordinates in `onpick()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t)
pt, = ax1.plot(t, s, picker=5)
mark, = ax1.plot([], [], '|r', markersize='20')


def onpick(event):
    if event.artist != pt:
        return True
    if not len(event.ind):
        return True
    ind = event.ind[0]
    mark.set_data(t[ind], s[ind])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return True


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT: same principle using N curves and N markers**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
ss = [np.sin(2 * 2 * np.pi * t),
      np.cos(3 * 2 * np.pi * t),
      np.sin(0.5 * 2 * np.pi * t)]
cs = ['b','r', 'g']
ms = ['|','o','D']
lines = [ax1.plot(t,s,'-',color=c, picker=5)[0] for s,c in zip(ss,cs)]
markers = [ax1.plot([],[],lw=0, marker=m, ms=20, color=c)[0] for m,c in zip(ms,cs)]

def onpick(event):
    point_idx = event.ind[0]
    art_idx = None
    for i,l in enumerate(lines):
        if event.artist == l:
            art_idx = i
            break
    if art_idx is not None:
        markers[art_idx].set_data(t[point_idx], ss[art_idx][point_idx])
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return True


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What if I now add second curve to the same 'ax1.plot' and want to pick second mark in the same figure ? Should I use class or is it any simpler  solution?

Comment: You can simply create two empty artists, and check which curve was clicked on and update the relevant artist. I've added an example.

Comment: OK, but honestly, i am looking for some solution for multiple time-series (not two but e.g. 100 curves). I used to plot them with loop. `for i in range(10): l1, = ax1.plot(t,s+i, picker=5`. It will be great to pick all curves in one figure

Comment: Sure, if your use case is starting to get complex, then splitting things in classes would probably be cleaner. However, it's pretty simple to maintain two lists, one for the lines and the other for the markers, and find which of the lines was clicked in the first list, and adjust the corresponding artists in the second list. I've amended my answer with 3 curves

Comment: Very helpful for me! Please, let me know why do you put `[0]` at the end of `ax1.plot(t,s,'-',color=c, picker=5)[0]` ?

Comment: because `plot()` always returns a list (you can create several lines with a single `plot()`). If I did not write `plot(...)[0]`, I would end up with a list of lists, which would make the syntax more complex. It's also the same reason you were using a comma at `pt` in `pt, = ax1.plot(t, s, picker=5)`